# Cannot read property 'error' of undefined in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

> Cannot read property 'error' of undefined in Angular 2?

During use of following code, I have code following error ,I think I have to import some proerty like `FormModule` in `module.ts`, but I don't not what is that?? Please help me to solve this?

```
Firstname: <input type="text" class="_firstname" name="txtFirstname"    [(ngModel)]="firstName" placeholder="Enter First Name"  #txtFather="ngModel"><br><br>
<div *ngIf="txtFirstname.error &&(txtFirstname.dirty || txtFirstname.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
    <div [hidden]="!txtFirstname.errors.required">
          Name  is required!
   </div>
</div>
```

> I've got:

```
reg.component.html:8 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (reg.component.html:9)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (services.ts:443)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:359)
    at callViewAction (view.ts:767)
    at execComponentViewsAction (view.ts:700)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:413)
    at callViewAction (view.ts:767)
    at execComponentViewsAction (view.ts:700)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:413)
    at callWithDebugContext (services.ts:815)
```

Comment: Well, your control variable is txtFather:  `#txtFather="ngModel"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't an element with name `txtFirstname`. You have used `#txtFather="ngModel"`, so you need to use `txtFather.error` instead of `txtFirstname.error`.

You have bind your input to the property `firstName`, but your control name is `txtFather`.

```
<input type="text" class="_firstname" name="txtFirstname" [(ngModel)]="firstName" placeholder="Enter First Name"  #txtFather="ngModel">
<br><br>
<div *ngIf="txtFather.error &&(txtFather.dirty || txtFather.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
   <div [hidden]="!txtFather.errors.required">
          Name  is required!
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: #Suran ,But Still its not working, Is there Any error

Comment: @Suran, thanks For Help,{ Actually I missed     'required'  in first line}

Answer (score 1):

Use `?` to check null / undefined values like this,

```
txtFirstname?.error
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to state following in the top area of your module.ts

```
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
```

And after that you need to put it in the "imports" brackets of the @NgModule Part

This is an example from the [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/forms):

```
@NgModule({


imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroFormComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is given because **txtFirstname** is undefined. It seems that you don't have such variable.